# Feature.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000000

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv, feature-detection

I am trying to detect and extract image feature using `DynamicAdaptedFeatureDetector`, but i am receiving Access violation error. The complete error is: `Unhandled exception at 0x000007FEE08AB89A (opencv_features2d2411d.dll) in Feature.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000000.`

my sample code is:

```
.
.
.
    Ptr<FeatureDetector> detector;
    vector<KeyPoint> keypoints1, keypoints2; 
    detector = new DynamicAdaptedFeatureDetector(new FastAdjuster(10, true), 5000, 10000, 10);
    detector->detect(leftImg_roi, keypoints1);
    detector->detect(rightImg_roi, keypoints2);

    Ptr<DescriptorExtractor> extractor;
    extractor = DescriptorExtractor::create("SIFT");
    Mat descriptors1, descriptors2;
    extractor->compute(leftImg_roi, keypoints1, descriptors1);
    extractor->compute(rightImg_roi, keypoints2, descriptors2);

    vector< vector<DMatch> > matches;
    Ptr<DescriptorMatcher> matcher = DescriptorMatcher::create("BruteForce");
    matcher->knnMatch(descriptors1, descriptors2, matches, 500);
.
.
.
```

Error is coming in the line: extractor->compute(rightImg_roi, keypoints2, descriptors2);

Total detected keypoints from images are: keypoints1 = 1649 and keypoints2 = 1558

Any idea whats wrong in my code?

Comment: Usually this indicates undefined behavior. You may want to check if you go out of bounds somewhere or use a deleted pointer or something else of the sort. In this case it looks like a null pointer exception `Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000000`

Comment: You seem to be using an old version of OpenCV, for example the newest libraries I have doesn't have anything like DynamicAdaptedFeatureDetector or FastAdjuster. Check if the return value of DescriptorExtractor::create("SIFT"); with extractor->empty(). It returns a bool. If it's false then the create() call failed.

Comment: @Zebrafish you are right, i am using Old opencv (2.4.11) due to some reason.Also extractor->empty()  is false that's why create() call is failing.

Comment: Using default SiftDescriptorExtractor works for me instead of create create("SIFT").                                                                                   
                                                                                     
DescriptorExtractor* extractor;
extractor = new SiftDescriptorExtractor();

Answer (score 1):

You are getting a `null pointer exception`. As you are trying to use a pointer that is null, the system is trying to read from address 0. This isn't allowed, hence the error: `Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000000`.

As you stated the error happens on the line where it uses the variable `extractor`. My guess is that `extractor` is null. If not, check other variables and try to use the `debugger` to step through your code. You aren't really providing a [minimal complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so I can't check myself.